# Upgraded Mythbuntu from 10.04 to 11.10 - Now no GUI display

Tags: 11.10, mythbuntu

Updated this weekend from 10.04 to 11.10 and now when I boot, I get the standard "Mythbuntu" boot screen then sections of text, then blank screen, then text, then blank scree, etc until I finally just get a black screen.

I am Running an ATI video card HDMI out to TV. I have tried other TV's, VGA Monitors, etc, all yield the same result.

How do I at least stop the boot process from loading the GUI and dumping me into CLI so I can start to fix this thing?

Thanks.

Comment: Besides doing what has been suggested to you, remember to uninstall the Graphics drivers, `FGLRX` if you have them installed as it can break when doing an upgrade.

Comment: You mean you upgraded to 10.10, then 11.04, then 11.10 right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been some reports of the lightdm transition not working properly for some people. Check your logs in /var/log/lightdm/

If there are errors about a unity-greeter, please remove the package 'unity-greeter' and make sure 'mythbuntu-lightdm-theme' is installed.

You may have to reconfigure automatic login too (there is no longer a GUI tool).

In summary:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get remove unity-greeter
sudo apt-get install lightdm
cd /etc/lightdm/
sudo mv lightdm.conf lightdm.conf.old
sudo nano lightdm.conf
```

In the lightdm.conf file put the following:

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=<<your mythtv user ID, ie: superm1 or whatever>>
autologin-user-timeout=0
autologin-session=lightdm-autologin
user-session=mythbuntu
allow-guest=false
```

Comment: Guys, thanks for the info!  I did sudo apt-get remove fglrx, then followed the instructions for lightdm, reboot, still just a black screen, so I did a sudo apt-get install fglrx, reboot and now it works!!  Yay...